# Approximately Conformal Boundary Conditions for a 2d CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions

Is there any work on approximately conformal boundary conditions for a two-dimensional CFT?

Consider a CFT on the upper-half-space $M$, and let the boundary conditions at the real line ($\partial M$) be

$$ T - \bar{T} |_{\partial M} = \epsilon, \qquad \epsilon \ll 1 $$

I feel like these must have nice properties in perturbation theory, but I couldn't find anything in my search of the literature.

Comment: Would a perturbative understanding be enough? This is the kind of thing you will get if you deform a BCFT with a weakly relevant operator.

Comment: Yes, that's perfect, thanks so much! Is there a standard reference?

Comment: Conformal boundary conditions are sort of fixed points of boundary RG flow. So you can certainly deform it by adding an irrelevant operator (adding relevant ones will take you away to something different). This might be a better way to think about it compared to just setting $T-\bar{T}$ to an arbitrary number .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the helpful comments by Connor Behan and Meng Cheng, who pointed out the related question I *should* have asked, I found a good introduction to the relevant literature in chapter 5 of *Boundary conformal field theory and the worldsheet approach to D-branes* by Andreas Recknagel and Volker Schomerus.